# Switch to different package

Tags: apt, docker, boost

I have to install `libboost-all-dev` 1.62+ and I found it here https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libboost-all-dev because I need 1.65.1, but I don't understand how to switch to bionic. Looks like by default `apt-get` tries to install the package from `xenial`, but there are no `1.62+`.

Actually, I use Docker, maybe it's possible to solve the problem somehow

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -q && apt-get -qy install \
    git sudo cmake build-essential cuda-8-0 \
    libboost1.65-all-dev
```

It throws an error on installing `libboost1.65-all-dev`

Comment: It suggest to download the file but is it possible to install using `apt-get` like I install from `xenial`?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a PPA or some other repository for 16.04 with that version of boost.